# Update to .NET 5 DataAnnotations.Schema don't work anymore. LINQ join multiple dbs / querys failing

Tags: entity-framework-core, schema, data-annotations, asp.net5, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

In Core 3.0 i could join multiple dbs / schemas.
Here is the class Order in dbEarth :

```
namespace dgNet.Core.Models.Earth
{
    [Table("tbl_Order", Schema ="Earth")]
    public class Order : EntityBaseWithTypedId<int>
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("BestID")]
        public override int Id { get; set; }
```

Here is class SerialNumber in dbMars

```
namespace dgNet.Core.Models.Mars
{

    [Table("tbl_serialnumber", Schema = "Mars")]
    public class SerialNumber : EntityBaseWithTypedId<int>
    {
        [Column("serialnumber")]
        public int Serialnumber { get; set; }

        [Column("jobId")]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("JobId")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }
```

Data Annotations is equivalent to the code here :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().ToTable("tbl_Order", "Earth");
}
```

So if builded a LINQ Query and included  Order(dbEarth)  in SerialNumber(dbMars) it worked well.

```
query => query.Include(serialNumber => serialNumber.Order).FirstOrDefault();
```

After the update to Core 5.0   SQL- Querys are created incorrectly.

SQL joins Orders on the same db / schema like SerialNumbers.

Using newest NuGet packages .AspCore (5.0.10)
DB = MySQL
Using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (5.0.2)

Someone has that problem?

Comment: Probably bug in Pomelo provider.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support the EF Core concept of schemas.

The EF Core concept of schemas is the same one that SQL Server uses, in which schemas are basically just categories (organization units) that you can use to group multiple tables logically together within the same database.

What MySQL calls schemas are actually databases, and a single `DbContext` does not support multiple databases in EF Core.

Therefore, we officially removed the very brittle multi-database support in Pomelo 3.2.0.

The official way to deal with this is shown in [Implement alternatives to the current behavior to always throw, if a schema has been set for an object #982](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/982):

> There are currently 3 options to choose from:
>
> ```cs
> // Throw an exception, if a schema is being used. This is the default.
> options.UseMySql(myConnectionString, b => b.SchemaBehavior(MySqlSchemaBehavior.Throw))
>
> // Silently ignore any schema definitions.
> options.UseMySql(myConnectionString, b => b.SchemaBehavior(MySqlSchemaBehavior.Ignore))
>
> // Use the specified translator delegate to translate from an input schema and object name to
> // an output object name whenever a schema is being used.
> options.UseMySql(myConnectionString, b => b.SchemaBehavior(MySqlSchemaBehavior.Translate,
>     (schema, entity) => $"{schema ?? "dbo"}_{entity}"))
> ```

There is also a way to explicitly enable the old behavior, as illustrated in 
[method ModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema is not working (No database selected)
#22971 (comment)](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22971#issuecomment-707768344) for Pomelo 3.2.x:

> [...]
>
> In essence, there are two steps:
>
> 1. You need to derive from `MySqlSqlGenerationHelper` and override `GetSchemaName`:
>
> ```cs
> public class CustomMySqlSqlGenerationHelper : MySqlSqlGenerationHelper
> {
>     public CustomMySqlSqlGenerationHelper(
>         RelationalSqlGenerationHelperDependencies dependencies,
>         IMySqlOptions options)
>         : base(dependencies, options)
>     {
>     }
>
>     protected override string GetSchemaName(string name, string schema)
>         => schema; // <-- this is the first part that is needed to map schemas to databases 
> }
> ```
>
> 1. You need to provide a schema name translator:
>
> ```cs
> optionsBuilder
>     .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider) // use our ServiceProvider
>     .UseMySql(
>         "server=127.0.0.1;port=3308;user=root;password=;database=EFCoreIssue22971_01_IceCreamParlor",
>         b => b.ServerVersion("8.0.21-mysql")
>             .SchemaBehavior(
>                 MySqlSchemaBehavior.Translate,
>                 (schemaName, objectName) => objectName) // <-- this is the second part that is needed to map
>                                                         //     schemas to databases
>             .CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend))
>     .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
>     .EnableDetailedErrors();
> ```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, on the same time i found on the same answer in your issues in the pomelo project! Nice 2 have that directly from you! Vielen Dank grüße aus der Schweiz!